How can I log the http response using middleware in azure functions running .NET 8 isolated process?
I am in the process of migrating my azure function from in-process to isolated process.
Since middleware is now supported in azure functions when running them in the isolated process model, I was hopping I could use the built-in services.AddHttpLogging(o => o.LoggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.All); and app.UseHttpLogging(); to log the http requests and responses. Unfortunately this seems not to be possible, since the second statement is not available in the IHost, which I get back when calling the .Build() statement on the HostBuilder.
So instead i started building my own middleware for this, but I am stuck on how to get access to the response body.
If I just call the GetHttpResponseData() from the FunctionContext I get "System.ArgumentException: 'Stream was not readable'" because the underlying StreamWriter was disposed.
I then tried replacing the httpContext.Response.Body with my own MemoryStream before sending the request further down the pipeline, which actually did allow me to get access to the response body, but then the response returned to the end user/caller is now always blank.
Here is the code when trying to access the response body stream directly:
public class RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware> logger;

    public RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware(ILogger<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
    }

    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var request = await context.GetHttpRequestDataAsync();
        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(request!.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        logger.LogInformation("RequestBody: {requestBody}", requestBody);

        await next(context);

        var response = context.GetHttpResponseData();
        string responseBody = await new StreamReader(response!.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        logger.LogInformation("ResponseBody: {responseBody}", responseBody);
    }
}

Which throws the 'Stream was not readable' error:

And here is the code when replacing the response stream with my own MemoryStream, which always returns a blank response to the end user/caller:
public class RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware> logger;

    public RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware(ILogger<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
    }

    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var request = await context.GetHttpRequestDataAsync();
        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(request!.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        logger.LogInformation("RequestBody: {requestBody}", requestBody);

        using (MemoryStream openResponseBody = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();
            httpContext!.Response.Body = openResponseBody;

            await next(context);

            var response = context.GetHttpResponseData();
            string responseBody = await GetResponseBody(response!.Body);
            logger.LogInformation("ResponseBody: {responseBody}", responseBody);
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> GetResponseBody(Stream responseBody)
    {
        responseBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        return await new StreamReader(responseBody).ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}


Found the solution.
Had to temporarily save the original response stream before calling await next(context);, and then once I was done reading the response body (which was possible after replacing the original response stream with a temporary MemoryStream) I had to copy the value from the temporary MemoryStream to the original stream.
Also, I was missing EnableBuffering() on the request body, as well as resetting its Position to 0, which was causing an exception for requests with a body, as the position of the request body stream was at the end when entering the controller.
Here is the final working code:
public class RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    private readonly ILogger<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware> logger;

    public RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware(ILogger<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
    }

    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var httpContext = context.GetHttpContext();

        logger.LogInformation("RequestBody: {requestBody}", await GetRequestBody(httpContext!.Request));

        using MemoryStream tempResponseBody = new MemoryStream();
        var originalResponseBody = httpContext!.Response.Body;
        httpContext!.Response.Body = tempResponseBody;

        await next(context);

        logger.LogInformation("ResponseBody: {responseBody}", await GetResponseBody(httpContext!.Response));

        await tempResponseBody.CopyToAsync(originalResponseBody);
    }

    private async Task<string> GetRequestBody(HttpRequest request)
    {
        request.EnableBuffering();
        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        return requestBody;
    }

    private async Task<string> GetResponseBody(HttpResponse response)
    {
        response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var responseBody = await new StreamReader(response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        response.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        
        return responseBody;
    }
}


Did you ever encounter an issue where context.GetHttpContext() always returns null?

This worked for an Azure Function App return HttpResponseData, is there a way to do the same when treating an Function like ASP.NET and returning IActionResult<>?
